# AngularJS refresh and stay at same scroll position

Tags: angularjs, scroll

I'd like a page refresh to resume the page from the last scroll position before the refresh was pressed.

I'm using AngularJS and something peculiar is happening because when I refresh it first goes to the top of the page, then as soon as I scroll it will resume from the last scroll position before I hit refresh.

Very odd behavior, no?

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr demonstration of your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about providing a route like `/app/:currentScrollTop`
and then you can based on that parameter to scroll your view to the desired position.